# How to get values from this XML?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to parse xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<matches>
    <round_1>
        <match_1>
            <home_team>team_5</home_team>
            <away_team>team_13</away_team>
            <home_goals_time>None</home_goals_time>
            <away_goals_time>24;37</away_goals_time>
            <home_age_average>27.4</home_age_average>
            <away_age_average>28.3</away_age_average>
            <score>0:2</score>
            <ball_possession>46:54</ball_possession>
            <shots>8:19</shots>
            <shots_on_target>2:6</shots_on_target>
            <shots_off_target>5:10</shots_off_target>
            <blocked_shots>1:3</blocked_shots>
            <corner_kicks>3:4</corner_kicks>
            <fouls>10:12</fouls>
            <offsides>0:0</offsides>
        </match_1>
    </round_1>
</matches>
```

I use standard library - xml but I can't get values from inner tags. That's my exemplary code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
TEAMS_STREAM = "data/stats1.xml"

tree = et.parse(TEAMS_STREAM)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter('home_goals_time'):
    print(elem.attrib)
```

It should work but it's not. I was trying to find issue in xml structure but I coludn't find it. I always got empty dict. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @chepner `root.iter` traverses the whole tree recursively https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `.attrib` on the element, but there are no attributes for those elements. If you want to print the inner text of the element, use `.text` instead of `.attrib`

```
for elem in root.iter('home_goals_time'):
    print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're having issues is that you need to parse through the xml level by level. Using `findall`, I was able to get the value inside `<home_goals_time>`.

```
for i in root.findall('.//home_goals_time'):
     print (i.text)
None
```